# Why does parsing "0000:00:00 00:00:00" into a Date return -0001-11-28T00:00:00Z?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

Why does the following code output `-0001-11-28T00:00:00Z` instead of `0000-00-00T00:00:00Z`?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
        parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = parser.parse("0000:00:00 00:00:00");
        System.out.println(date.toInstant());
    }
}
```

My first thought was that this was a time-zone problem, but the output is a whopping 34 days earlier than the expected date.

This is a 3rd-party library so I cannot actually modify the code but if I can understand why it is returning this value then maybe I can tweak the inputs to get the desired output.

In case you're wondering, `0000:00:00 00:00:00` comes from [EXIF metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) of images or videos.

Comment: I'd check the source code and maybe debug, but presumably the issue is in how month 0 and day 0 are interpreted during parsing given that they don't make sense in a formatted date (I don't think!)

Comment: Can be reproduced on ideone: https://ideone.com/QUc6P8

Comment: First of all, there was no year numbered zero (the concept of zero didn't exist).  Dates go from 1 BC to 1 AD, which explains the year being `-0001`.  As to the additional 34 days... there's probably a good explanation.  At least 10 days of that shift may have to do with the Gregorian calendar adjustment.  This may _also_ have to do with the fact that `java.util.Date` is deprecated. You should try this with the `java.time.*` classes.

Comment: Even month 0 and day 0 are illegal... Months are 1-12, and days are 1-31 (or less depending on the month and the year)

Comment: trying with `2000:00:00 00:00:00` looks like it basically takes `2000-01-01` as a starting point then subtracts a month and one day from it for the reasons given by. @xanatos immediately above, ending up with `1999-11-30T00:00:00Z`

Comment: 0000 numbered year issue aside, there's some interesting points in history where calendars were changed/adjusted like when 10 whole days were lost when the Gregorian calendar was adopted in 1582 and Nov 18 1883 in the US when standardized timezones were adopted - if you manipulate dates before/after this point you'll find you lose 7mins 2seconds.

Comment: Following up on @KevinHooke's comment about the Gregorian calendar: If you use `01` for the day and month, then you get the expected output using years from 1583 onwards (example: `1583-01-01T00:00:00Z`). Prior to 1582 (when there was that 10 day shift), there is a step backwards of 1 year at the turn of each century, the further back in time you go. But also, if the century was a leap-year, it looks like that canceled out the effect of this backwards step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by other answers, this is a result of processing an invalid timestamp (invalid year, month and day values) with a legacy class (`SimpleDateFormat`) that doesn't do proper validation.

In short ... garbage in, garbage out<sup>1</sup>.

Solutions:

1. Rewrite the code that uses `SimpleDateFormat` to use the new date / time classes introduced in Java 8.  (Or use a backport if you have to use Java 7 and earlier.)
2. Work around the problem by testing for this specific case before you attempt to process the string as a date.

   It seems from the context that "0000:00:00 00:00:00" is the EXIF way of saying "no such datetime".  If that's the case, then trying to treat it as a datetime seems counter-productive.  Treat it as a special case instead.
3. If you can't rewrite the code or work around the problem, submit a bug report and/or patch against the (3rd party) library and hope for the best ...

---

<sup>1 - Why the discrepancy is exactly 1 year and 34 days is a bit of a mystery, but I'm sure you could figure out the explanation by diving into the source code.  IMO, it is not worth the effort.  However, I can't imagine why the Gregorian shift would be implicated in this ...</sup>

Comment: You are right that the string in question is coming from EXIF metadata.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is no differentiation between *year-of-era* and *year* in the legacy API. The year, `0` is actually `1 BC`. The month, `0` and day, `0` are invalid values but instead of throwing an exception `SimpleDateFormat` parses them erroneously.

**The reason for the month being converted to `11`:**

The `SimpleDateFormat` decreases the month numeral in the text by `1` because `java.util.Date` is `0` based. In other words, month, `1` is parsed by `SimpleDateFormat` as `0` which is month `Jan` for `java.util.Date`. Similarly, month, `0` is parsed by `SimpleDateFormat` as `-1`. Now, a neagtive month is treated by `java.util.Date` as follows:

```
month = CalendarUtils.mod(month, 12);
```

and the `CalendarUtils#mod` has been defined as follows:

```
public static final int mod(int x, int y) {
    return (x - y * floorDivide(x, y));
}
public static final int floorDivide(int n, int d) {
    return ((n >= 0) ?
            (n / d) : (((n + 1) / d) - 1));
}
```

Thus, `CalendarUtils.mod(-1, 12)` returns `11`.

`java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are full of such surprises. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

### The modern date-time API:

The modern date-time API differentiates between *year-of-era* and *year* using `y` and `u` respectively.

`y` specifies the *year-of-era* (era is specified as `AD` or `BC`) and is always a positive number whereas `u` specifies the *year* which is a signed (+/-) number.

Normally, we do not use `+` sign to write a positive number but we always specify a negative number with a `-` sign. The same rule applies for a *year*. As long as you are going to use a year of the era, `AD`, both, `y` and `u` will give you the same number. However, you will get different numbers when you use a year of the era, `BC` e.g. the *year-of-era*, `1 BC` is specified as *year*, `0`; the *year-of-era*, `2 BC` is specified as *year*, `-1` and so on.

You can understand it better with the following demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(-1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y M d")));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(1, 1, 1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yG M d")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-1 1 1
2 1 1
2BC 1 1

0 1 1
1 1 1
1BC 1 1

1 1 1
1 1 1
1AD 1 1
```

### How does modern date-time API treat `0000:00:00 00:00:00`?

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu:MM:dd HH:mm:ss")
                                                    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                                                    .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("0000:00:00 00:00:00", parser);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000:00:00 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
....
```

**With `DateTimeFormatter#withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)`:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
        String str = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-0001-11-30T00:00
```

Comment: How does `-0001-11-28T00:00:00Z` relate to the input `0000-00-00T00:00:00Z`?

Comment: @MartinSmith - `SimpleDateFormat` is full of such surprises. Currently, I am writing some code to find out the reason for the difference. I'll update my answer with my findings.

Comment: Can you please reword the section `difference occurs when you use a year of the era`? I don't understand what you are trying to say there. It sounds like a run-on sentence.

Comment: @Gili - I've reworded it. I hope it's clear now. What I've tried to say is that for `AD` the numbers will be the same while for `BC` the numbers will be different. I've given a couple of examples in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is because year 0 is invalid, it doesn't
exist.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero

Month,day are also invalid by being 0.

Comment: This doesn't explain the extra 34 days

Comment: There isn't 34 day difference, because you can't compare it to an invalid input. The 34 day difference would exist only if the input would be 0001-01-01 and the result would be still -0001-11-28.